# How to prevent pasting text in a numeric column in Aggrid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I did the cell editor for numeric column which accepts only number. But I am in trouble while pasting text which should not happen. 
Here is the code I am using.

```js
processCellFromClipboard: function (params) {
    params.column.colDef.suppressPaste = false;
    if (
        params.column.colDef.type == "numericColumn" &&
        isNaN(params.value)
    ) {
        console.log("isNaN(params.value)", isNaN(params.value));
        params.column.colDef.suppressPaste = false;
        //throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');

        //return null;
    } else {
        return params.value;
    }
},
```

Please have a look and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the line

```
isNaN(params.value)
```

isNaN takes a number as a parameter.
You can't pass, say, a string to isNaN and expect a reasonable result.
Try

```
isNaN(Number(params.value))
```

I could be wrong, but I'm also guessing that regardless of what the data looks like, when you paste from the clipboard, it's probably text, and if you want a number, you're going to have to do `Number(params.value)` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.I tried this way and it helps me not to paste string in a numeric column. But if i paste a string on a number it is making the cell as blank or empty.it should not make the cell empty or should not paste there. What can i do here.Please help.

Comment: the 'params' argument should have a 'rowNode' property, which has a 'data' property, which is your object backing the row. Get the value of the cell from that, and return it, so that it will retain it's current value.

Comment: At least for me, the `params.node.data` property has been updated after paste, and ends up with undefined and null values

Answer (score -3):

try html

```
<input type="number">
```